# C# and Generics: how can I handle processing based on type?

Tags: c#, generics, dotnet-httpclient

I'm new to generics and I'm trying to make a generic HTTP GET method for my project (and possibly expand it to handle POST/PUT also). The following seems to work OK when the response is string based:

```
private async Task<T> HttpGetAsync<T>(Uri uri)
{
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = uri,
        Headers =
        {
            { "Authorization", $"Basic {encodedCredentials}"},
            { "Cache-Control", "no-cache" }
        }
    };

    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
}
```

But in some cases, based on the type, I would like the response to be read using ReadAsByteArrayAsync() or ReadAsStreamAsync() instead of ReadAsStringAsync().

I think that I could probably do a getType() within the method, and read the response using the appropriate method, but I'm wondering if maybe there is a better way to do this?

Is this a bad idea/a bad usage of generics in general? Thanks for any information!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an interface:

```
interface IContentReader<T>
{
    T ReadAsync(HttpResponseMessage response);
}

private async Task<T> HttpGetAsync<T>(Uri uri, IContentReader<T> reader)
{
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = uri,
        Headers =
        {
            { "Authorization", $"Basic {encodedCredentials}"},
            { "Cache-Control", "no-cache" }
        }
    };

    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    return await reader.ReadAsync(response);
}
```

And you can have different implementations of `IContentReader<T>`.
You can determine which implementation to use based on `T`.

Comment: Hmm, requiring the caller to pass in an `IContentReader` implementation feels like a bit of a leaky abstraction to me. I might opt for just using a good old switch statement here, maybe it a separate method.

Comment: @ToddMenier I agree with you on that the caller should not pass an interface to the method, this is just to show the OP how the reading of the content could be abstracted out of the method itself. In reality, `IContentReader` or the factory of the type could be injected into the class where the method is defined, and that will simplify the method a bit.